# Why doesn't GHCi allow type arguments for this version of join?

Tags: haskell, types

I've tried toying around with `TypeApplications`, and used the following:

```
 join = (>>= id)
 :t join
join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
 :t join @[]
```

But I get the following error:

```
<interactive>:1:1: error:
    * Cannot apply expression of type `m0 (m0 b0) -> m0 b0'
      to a visible type argument `[]'
    * In the expression: join @[]
```

This, in my view, should work, as

```
 :t fmap @[]
fmap @[] :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

works.

Comment: Note it *would* work if you used `Control.Monad.join`, instead of your own definition, for the reasons given in [luqui's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53106377/1126841).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Type applications only work for definitions that have explicit type signatures.

```
>>> join :: (Monad m) => m (m a) -> m a; join = (>>= id)
>>> :t join @[]
join @[] :: [[a]] -> [a]
```

All the gory details (and there are quite a few) of this extension are in the paper [Visible Type Application](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~sweirich/papers/type-app-extended.pdf).

Comment: If you add `:set -fprint-explicit-foralls` then `:info join` gives the type as `forall {m :: * -> *} {a}. Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`, while `:info` for the version from `Control.Monad` shows as `forall (m :: * -> *) a. …`—as in the paper, the curly braces indicate that a type parameter isn’t from a type signature and thus can’t be used with visible type applications.

Comment: Why does `:type join` still give `{a}` even if the type signature is explicit?

Comment: @MarkNeu, my guess is that `:type join` is asking about the *expression* `join`, i.e. a particular use of it, where the type variables have been instantiated and then re-abstracted.  Whereas `:info` join is asking about the `join` definition itself.  /cc @JonPurdy

Comment: @schuelermine To see either `(..)` or `{..}` you need to do both `:set -fprint-explicit-foralls` and then ask with `:type +v test`.